# How to work with DateTime with doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I've always used "date" and "timestamp" types in my mapping and then dealt with DateTime's everywhere in the objects. Suddenly I'm getting MongoDate and MongoTimestamp objects. Is this a purposeful change or a bug?

Running latest symfony and doctrine master branches.

Comment: It might be wiser to open an issue on DoctrineMongoDBBundle for this, as it might be related to recent mapping refactoring. Can you specify the commit hashes for DoctrineMongoDBBundle, mongodb-odm, mongodb and common?

Comment: Please, read: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions

Comment: @FabianoLothor: this question pertains to Doctrine ODM's mapping for types used by the PHP Mongo driver (e.g. MongoDate), as described here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types